# How to exactly calculate the chemical potential in the density matrix from the expectation value of the conserved quantities?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, computational-physics

We know that the equilibrium state of an integrable model can be described by a generalized Gibbs ensemble (GGE). Suppose, we have an integrable model where all the conserved charges are given by $Z_i$ where $Z_i$ is the Pauli-Z operator at site i. (This is just for an example, in actual case the charges may look much complicated). Now, I know all the $\langle Z_i \rangle$ in the initial state. So,we can write

$$
\langle Z_i \rangle=\frac{Tr[ Z_i exp(-\beta_iZ_i)]}{N}
$$

where $\rho=\frac{exp(-\beta_iZ_i)}{N}$ is the density matrix of the system and $\beta_i$ are the chemical potentials, I have to solve for. N is just a normalization factor. It is not clear to me how to solve this equation to obtain all the  $\beta_i$. There will be L such equations for an L-site system (In this example, we are considering local Pauli-Z operator  $ Z_i$ as conserved charges). Those operators commute with each other and they are traceless. I can expand the expression in straightforward manner to get the following,
\begin{align}
\langle Z_k \rangle &= Tr [Z_k exp(-\Sigma_i \beta_i Z_i)]\\
                    &= Tr [Z_k exp(- \beta_k Z_k)]\Pi_{i \neq k}Tr [Z_i exp(- \beta_i Z_i)]\\
&= 2^L sinh(\beta_k) \Pi_{i \neq k}cosh(\beta_k)
\end{align}

Is this a good way to do this? I have L equations for L variables but they are coupled in a complicated manner. Is there a simpler way to obtain the $\beta_i$? What would be a good numerical routine to calculate this? Any help/comment will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether you were using Einstein convention, but either you meant:
$$
\rho = \frac{1}{N}\exp\left(\sum_i \beta_iZ_i\right)
$$
or you meant that at each site you have:
$$
\rho_i = \frac{1}{N_i}\exp\left(\beta_iZ_i\right)
$$
In any case, the $\rho_i$ are the marginals of $\rho$ and conversely (since the $Z_i$ commute):
$$
\rho = \prod_i\rho_i
$$
You either have $L+1$ independent equations for $L+1$ unknowns $\beta_i, N$:
$$
\text{Tr}\rho = 1\\
\text{Tr}[\rho Z_i] = \bar Z_i
$$
or you equivalently have $L$ independent systems of $2$ equations for $2L$ unknowns $\beta_i,N_i$:
$$
\text{Tr}\rho_i = 1\\
\text{Tr}[\rho_i Z_i] = \overline Z_i
$$
In either case the system is easy to solve, using:
$$
\text{Tr}\rho_i = \cosh\beta_i \\
\text{Tr}[\rho_i Z_i] = \sinh \beta_i
$$

Hope this helps.